# How to detect checked checkbox in other pages of datatables pagination using php?

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

How to detect checked checkbox in other pages of datatables pagination using php without using script or AJAX?

I was able to pass only one pagination page values to `$_POST`.

Comment: Since datatables is a jQuery plugin it runs on the client - so I'm pretty sure you can't do this with PHP (which runs on the server).

Comment: You can try to make a checkbox with a unique name like "checkbox-{pagenumber}".